# Accessing sqlalchemy Foreign Key relationship information programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build tests for flask-sqlalchemy models to confirm they match the tables in the database. Using reflection, I can get the db tables, columns, and foreign keys. With the models I know how to check tablename and column names, but I can't figure out how to see the defined foreign key relationships programatically.

Model example:

```
class Example(db.Model):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'defined_schema'}
    __tablename__ = 'example'

    id =          db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name =        db.Column(db.String)
    info =        db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey(Info.id))
    descr =       db.Column(db.String)
```

Given a Model m, I've tried:

```
dir(m)
m.__dict__
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using     `sqlalchemy.inspect(model).columns.foreign_keys` and a bit of string manipulation, I was able to compare model foreign key relationships to those in the DB